# Making different figures on canvas html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a canvas but I don't know how to create other figure in the same canvas which overlay it, I have 2 buttons, one to puts images and then link it and make a figure and other to puts another image but in a different figure.
For example you have the button "a" and button "b". The button "a" puts images and make the figure linking the images. Now you want to start a new figure, you use the button "b", puts a image, and when you back to button "a" it must link the new image that buttons "b" has put before. I don't know If I'm explaining well.
I'll try to pass a variable to compare if you are using one button or another to use the same function to draw. the variable is `nF`, `if nF=0` => button "a" `if nF=1`=>button "b"

Here is my code

```
    function position(year, mon) { //that function puts the images in the html
    $('#' + year + ' .' + mon).prepend('<img class="black_point" src="./images/circle.png"/>');

}

    function draw(nF) {
    var fN = nF;
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var images = table.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x, y; // Remember coordinates

    canvas.width = table.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = table.offsetHeight;

    function connect(image, index) { //this function link the images
        var tabBcr = table.getBoundingClientRect();
        var imgBcr = image.getBoundingClientRect();
        x = imgBcr.left + (imgBcr.width / 2) - tabBcr.left;
        y = imgBcr.top + (imgBcr.height / 2) - tabBcr.top;

        index === 0 ? ctx.moveTo(x, y) : ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.save(); //save the state I think
    }
    // new path here
    ctx.beginPath();

    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        connect(images[i], i); // provide index so we can sep. move/line
    }
 if (fN == 1) {//This doesn't work :(
        ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
        ctx.fill();
        cxt.restore();

    } else {
        // then at the end:
        ctx.fill();
        cxt.restore();

    }

}
```

[image: This is one figure, you add the circles using "add person"]

[image: when you use "add new family", there should be two figures but there are mixed]

Comment: Can you create a picture to show the different elements (table, images and buttons) and to show the result you want to achieve?

Comment: okey I added some pictures, maybe now is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since the original description in your question differs greatly from your newly added images, I offer this code as a learning starting point without explanation:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

ctx.lineWidth=2;
var colors=['green','blue','gold','cyan'];

var figures=[];
var selectedFigure=-1;
var circles=[];
var selectedCircle=-1;
var connectors=[];

addFigure();

$('#new').attr('disabled',true);

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

$('#new').click(function(){
  addFigure();
});


///// functions

function addFigure(){
  figures.push({
    circleCount:0,
    color:randomColor(),
    lastCX:0,
    lastCY:0
  });
  selectedFigure=figures.length-1;
}

function addCircle(mx,my){

  var figure=figures[selectedFigure];

  var circle={
    id:circles.length,
    cx:mx,
    cy:my,
    radius:15,
    figure:selectedFigure,
    color:figure.color,
  };
  circles.push(circle);

  if(figure.circleCount>0){
    var connector={
      figure:selectedFigure,
      x0:figure.lastCX,
      y0:figure.lastCY,
      x1:mx,
      y1:my,
    }
    connectors.push(connector);
  }
  figure.lastCX=mx;
  figure.lastCY=my;
  figure.circleCount++;

  selectedCircle=circle.id;

  $('#new').attr('disabled',false);
}

function drawAll(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<connectors.length;i++){
    drawConnector(connectors[i]);
  }
  for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
    drawCircle(circles[i]);
  }
}

function drawCircle(circle){
  var highlighted=(circle.figure==selectedFigure);
  ctx.strokeStyle=(highlighted)?'red':'black';
  ctx.lineWidth=(circle.id==selectedCircle)?6:2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(circle.cx,circle.cy,circle.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fillStyle=circle.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.lineWidth=2;
}

function drawConnector(connector){
  var highlighted=(connector.figure==selectedFigure);
  ctx.strokeStyle=(highlighted)?'red':'lightgray';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(connector.x0,connector.y0);
  ctx.lineTo(connector.x1,connector.y1);
  ctx.stroke();
}


function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  if(selectedFigure<0){return;}

  var mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  var mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  var wasCircleClicked=false;;
  for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
    var c=circles[i];
    var dx=mouseX-c.cx;
    var dy=mouseY-c.cy;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy<=c.radius*c.radius){
      selectedFigure=c.figure;
      selectedCircle=i;
      var figure=figures[selectedFigure];
      figure.lastCX=c.cx;
      figure.lastCY=c.cy;
      wasCircleClicked=true;
      break;
    }                
  }

  if(!wasCircleClicked){
    addCircle(mouseX,mouseY);
  }

  drawAll();

}

function randomColor(){
  if(colors.length>0){
    var color=colors[0];
    colors.splice(0,1);
    return(color);
  }else{
    return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click on empty area to add a circle to the currently selected figure.<br><br>Click on a circle to select its figure.<br>Selected figures have a red stroke.<br>New circles will be connected to the last-clicked circle.</h4>
<button id=new>Add new figure</button><br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=300></canvas>
```

**Here's a framework for displaying the people of different families.**

[image]
[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// vars
var selectedFamily=0;
var nextFamily=0;
var families=[];

// set listeners

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

$(document).on('change','.fam',function(){
  selectedFamily=this.value;
  $('#focusFamily').text('Click canvas to add person to family#'+selectedFamily);
  draw();
});

$('#addfamily').click(function(){ addFamily(); });

// add a first family
addFamily();

// functions

function addFamily(){
  families.push({id:nextFamily,people:[]});

  var id=nextFamily;

  var input=$('<input type=radio />');
  input.prop({
    'value':nextFamily,
    'id':'fam'+nextFamily,
    'name':'fams',
    'class':'fam',
    'checked':'checked',
  });
  var label=$('<label>',{
    'for':'fam'+nextFamily,
    'html':'Work on Family#'+nextFamily,
  });
  $('#family').append('<br>').append(input).append(label);

  selectedFamily=nextFamily;

  nextFamily++;

  draw();

}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  families[selectedFamily].people.push({x:mx,y:my});

  draw();
}

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  var people=families[selectedFamily].people;
  for(var i=0;i<people.length;i++){
    var person=people[i];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(person.x,person.y,15,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke()
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#container{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  border:1px solid blue;
  padding:10px;
}
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br>
<h4 id=focusFamily>Click canvas to add person to family#0</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<div id=container>
  <button id=addfamily>Add Family</button>
  <div id=family></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'll tried to copy your code to learn how works but I don't know why doesn't take the canvas, `var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");` it returns null, and I don't know why, it's okey in the html

Comment: You've named you canvas 'miCanvas' and my example names the canvas 'canvas' so adjust like this: `var canvas=document.getElementById('miCanvas');`. BTW, the way I understood your original text question is much different than after you added your images. So my answer would have been quite different if you had originally included the images. My answer still does have some code applicable to your images. ;-)

Comment: But I'm  using your html code, yes it's useful for me but i can't use it -.-''

Comment: I've added to my answer. It's a framework for focusing on a family (selected by radio button) and adding people to just the selected family.

Comment: Yeah that was usefull, I can do it with that, I just have to puts together the families and draw the lines, thanks I can do it!